# make a docker container from daemon

Tags: docker, daemon, container

I'm using a microservices architecture. I already developed my daemon services (shell script). Now I want to run each of them in a docker container. I am new in docker, so I need some recommendations like docs or tutorial which guide me on how to attach these daemons to containers and how to ensure the communication between them.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you create an Docker image with a Dockerfile that:

- derives some image[1] (`FROM debian`)
- installs whatever additional package you need to tun your script (`RUN apt install ...`)
- copies your script to the image (`COPY daemonscript.sh /opt/daemonscript.sh`)
- sets the script as the thing to run: `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","/opt/daemonscript.sh","parm1","parm2"]

Once you have the image you can run it, possibly using "bind-mounts" to associate data directories for your container to directories on your host if you need to persist data across runs[2]

To run several containers together, the simpler way is to use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/)

[1] to pick the right image, one usually looks around for an image where additional installation in kept to a minimum, but at the same time it not oveloaded with unnecessary luggage. You find ready-to-run images for about anything: Apache, nginx, python, wordpress, mysql..

[2] keeping data in the container instance is a bad habit, a container should be considered "transient", and of course the docker image is immutable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I started creating my dockerfile, next I creat an image but when I want to create a container from this image I get the following error 'could not open input file /var/www/....'

Comment: Time to ask another question, and include the complete Dockerfile in the question.